# How do I share a bucket across accounts, to where no files do not need re-applying permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I current apply permissions to a bucket like this

```
gsutil acl ch -u service@account:O gs://my-bucket/
gsutil acl ch -r -u service@account:O gs://my-bucket/*
```

Then I add a file and the above permissions don't get applied, I have to reapply them.

Is there any way to apply the permissions to all new files added to bucket? I would want to share these files with 5 different projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this, is share a user across multiple project.

In the project you created the bucket, you create a service account that has only the right to access the bucket. Then you share this account with the other 4 projects.

With this you won't have to reapply rights each time and you can access your datas.